# gradle bootdebug: application fails to start and build fails

Tags: java, gradle, guice

I am trying to run my backend project to invoke an API to get the data of a patient within our HOMOL environment

Unfortunately when in try to run the command "gradle bootrun/bootdebug/runapp", my gradle throws up the following error.
This is bugging me from a week now and still i am clueless as of what i am missing here.

Any help to solve this?

```
"Exception:
C:\Java\Projects\process tasy\tasy-tws\tasy-tws-backend\tws-backend\philips-ms-exam>gradle runapp
:philips-ms-commons:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:philips-ms-commons:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:philips-ms-commons:classes UP-TO-DATE
:philips-ms-commons:jar
:philips-ms-app-boot:compileJava
:philips-ms-app-boot:processResources UP-TO-DATE`enter code here`
:philips-ms-app-boot:classes
:philips-ms-app-boot:jar
:philips-ms-exam:compileBootJava UP-TO-DATE
:philips-ms-exam:processBootResources UP-TO-DATE
:philips-ms-exam:bootClasses UP-TO-DATE
:philips-ms-exam:compileJava
:philips-ms-exam:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:philips-ms-exam:classes
:philips-ms-exam:pathingJar
:philips-ms-exam:bootRun
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error instantiating application

1 error
        at com.philips.app.boot.PhilipsBoot.main(PhilipsBoot.java:33)
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error instantiating main module

1 error
        at com.philips.app.boot.PhilipsInjector.loadMainModule(PhilipsInjector.java:174)
        at com.philips.app.boot.PhilipsInjector.<init>(PhilipsInjector.java:35)
        at com.philips.app.boot.PhilipsInjector.fromParams(PhilipsInjector.java:45)
        at com.philips.app.boot.PhilipsBoot.main(PhilipsBoot.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.philips.tws.boot.GuiceModule
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at com.philips.app.boot.PhilipsInjector.loadMainModule(PhilipsInjector.java:170)
        ... 3 more
:philips-ms-exam:bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':philips-ms-exam:bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 45.38 secs"
```

Comment: The message is quite clear: there's a missing class. Have you configured classpath properly?

Comment: I guess so the classpath is configured properly, the same project works perfectly on the system of my co-workers and yet for some reason it doesn't let me bootrun on my system